# Launching std::thread using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

When you construct a new thread the supplied function object is copied into the storage belonging to the newly created thread. I want to execute an object method in a new thread. The object should not be copied. So I pass  `shared_ptr` of the object to `std::thread` constructor. How can I launch a new thread with `std::shared_ptr()` object? For example

```
class Foo {
public: 
    void operator()() {       
        // do something
    }    
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr(new Foo);

    // I want to launch a foo_ptr() in a new thread
    // Is this the correct way?
    std::thread myThread(&Foo::operator(), foo_ptr.get());  
    myThread.join();     
}
```

Comment: _`// Is this the correct way?`_ Obviously not. Post a [MCVE], when asking about code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It may be obvious to you. I think the example is very minimal and to the point. If one needs clarification he could just ask and I'll be happy to provide more detail

Comment: Include all error messages and observations in your question please, that's what the linked policy says. VTC your question because of lacking this now, good evening.

Comment: Maybe. Let's see in the long term. I'm just doing what I'm feeling obliged to, keeping the quality standards of the site.

Comment: [Evidence of what's obviously missing](http://ideone.com/c8FCHa).

Comment: you are nitpicking on missing includes and small stuff. Just let it go..

Comment: [Asked on Meta for justification](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306368/questions-about-code-missing-a-mcve-should-we-close-vote).

Comment: I'm your soup nazi here of course ;-). Please improve your question, to be complete and helpful for future research.

Comment: :) I'm no longer engaging in this. I believe the question is clear as is. If you feel like the question should be closed it's fine. If you want to improve it by editing, it's fine too.

Comment: _"If you want to improve it by editing, it's fine too."_ As mentioned in my meta question, I'd say that's your job actually.

Comment: Look I've edited a number of other user's questions to improve their quality.  Even though my code was a sketch, it's very minimal and clear.  This site has helpful community in general. I don't support the way you handle this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You overcomplicate the issue, just pass `std::shared_ptr` itself, `std::bind` and `std::thread` know how to deal with it:

```
std::thread myThread( &Foo::operator(), foo_ptr );
```

This way `std::thread` instance will share ownership and that would guarantee object would not be destroyed before `myThread`

Comment: Would that keep a reference to the `shared_ptr` when `detach()` is called on `thread` and the `thread` object is destroyed?

Comment: I tested it in MSVC: seems it does keep the shared_ptr refcount alive after detach. https://ideone.com/S9ZLyG

Answer (score 5):

You have a lot of errors in you sketch code. I think a more readable way would be to use a lambda that captures the sptr by value and then deferences it to call the function.

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

class Foo
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        printf("do something\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo_ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();

    std::thread myThread([foo_ptr] { (*foo_ptr)(); });
    myThread.join();
}
```

It is not perfectly clear what you want to do. If you want to launch a new thread that runs a member function without copying the class instance the syntax would be one of those:

```
Foo foo;
std::thread th1(&Foo::moo, &foo);
std::thread th2([&]{ foo.moo(); });
```

Comment: Isn't a `std::make_shared` missing also?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. The code actually worked when testing, because the member function does not use the `this` pointer.